How to enter associated token address in solana playground?
I was following a youtube tutorial to mint nft tokens on solana playground. I wanna add Associated token address. In this tutorial there was an option to generate this using the owner account and mint account. Currently there's no such option called Associated token address. I only see in the drop down Random, Current Wallet, All wallets, From seed, Accounts. How do I generate the Associated token address on solana playground?

After compiling and deploying your program, when filling in the accounts, clicking the tokenAccount field should bring up a dropdown with the possible token account options

I am guessing what you are looking for is from My address
